# how to make my input only from the external mic instead of both built-in mic and the external

Tags: 11.10, sound, microphone, input

I have a problem with my microphone. I want to record sound with my external microphone, but it picks up sound from built-in laptop microphone too, and it makes noise. my input settings only shows option for analog michrophone(ext. and built-in mic)and analog line-in(from built-in mic). what should i do to make the input only from the external mic, instead of two mics?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and found that Unity is a bit tricky, because were not used to see the drop down menu at the bottom of the hardware tab.

Anyway, step 1: Click the speaker icon. Select sound settings. Select "sound".

Plan A: Select tab "hardware" select the internal microphone. In the drop down menu underneath it, select "off".

Plan B: Select tab "hardware" select the internal microphone. Select tab input and mark the microphone as "mute".